# Installing Python Tools for Visual Studio 2012 (PTVS)

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

I installed the version for VS 2010 a few weeks ago, and it went flawlessly. I am not having such good luck for the version for VS 2012. What did I do wrong? I ran, in order, two installers from Microsoft, "vs_isoshell.exe", "vs_intshelladditional.exe", and then "PTVS 1.5RC VS 2012.msi". VS Shell 2012 came up, and the Python support appeared to be present. I used the Wizard to create a new Python project. It will not run when I click to debug it. Also, VS Shell does not display the bottom of the window correctly either. VS 2010 Shell and PTVS still work perfectly.

What is the procedure for installing the 2012 version?

EDIT: I see that the instructions for installing the 2010 version say to uninstall previous versions first. I am reluctant to uninstall the 2010 version. If I uninstall PTVS and run PTVS 1.5RC VS 2012.msi, will PTVS still work in VS 2010 Shell?

[Isolated shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30670)

[Integrated shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30663)

[PTVS](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue w/ the VS integrated shell and debugging 64-bit applications.  That may have been what you were encountering.  1.5 RTM includes a workaround for that issue.