# Python in Visual Studio 2010 (PVTS) can't debug

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, debugging, ptvs

I have Visual Studio 2010 Shell and Python 2.7.8 on my machine and I installed PTVS 2.1.1 VS 2010.  Everything appeared to install correctly.  I can create a python application and run the code using 'Debug > Start Without Debugging'.  This pops up the python shell and works as expected.  I can also do 'Debug > Execute Project in Python Interactive'.  However if I just do 'Debug > Start Debugging' the python shell opens and than hangs.  The only thing I can do is close it.  If I insert break points it doesn't recognize them and will run the code, using the previously stated commands, without hitting the break points and allowing me to debug.  On the Debug toolbar in VS studio the only active button is 'Start Debugging'.  Pause, Stop, etc. are all grayed out.

I have searched and and found only these two articles but they don't relate and the later says their issue is resolved in VS 2010 which is what I'm using?

[Installing Python Tools for Visual Studio 2012 (PTVS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678916/installing-python-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-ptvs)

[Python in Visual Studio (PTVS): Debug not working but Run works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582683/python-in-visual-studio-ptvs-debug-not-working-but-run-works)

Unfortunately, this is on a clients machine and I am stuck with the installations of VS, Python, and cannot uninstall/reinstall VS, Python, or PTVS.  This may make it impossible to solve but I wanted to see if anyone knew of a solution.  I have everything installed on another machine with the same VS 2010, Python 2.7.8, and PTVS 2.1.1 and it works fine.  I am at a loss as to why it would be messed up on the other one machine and not the other?